# Javascript remove semicolon from last string

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, object

```js
const arr = [
    {
        "id": "753311",
        "role": "System Of Record (SOR)",
        "license": "Target",
        "DC": "Client · L2 (Inactive), Account · L1",
        "managedGeography": "North America · L2, International · L2",
        "managedSegment": "Institutional Clients Group [L3], Discontinued Ops [L2]",
        "checked": true,
        "checkBoxPatched": true
    },
    {
        "id": "752872",
        "role": "Authorized Redistributor (AR)",
        "license": "Interim",
        "DC": "Holding · L1, Document · L1, Compliance · L1",
        "managedGeography": "Unspecified",
        "managedSegment": "Unspecified",
        "checked": true,
        "checkBoxPatched": true
    },
    {
        "id": "752583",
        "role": "Authorized Redistributor (AR)",
        "license": "Target",
        "DC": "Agreement · L1, Asset · L1, Activity · L1, Account · L1",
        "managedGeography": "Unspecified",
        "managedSegment": "Unspecified"
    }
]

let adsList = arr.map(selectedObj => {
        if (selectedObj.checked) {
          return selectedObj.role + ", " + selectedObj.license + ", " + selectedObj.DC + ", " + selectedObj.managedGeography + ", " + selectedObj.managedSegment + ";\n"
        } else {
          return '';
        }
      }).filter((str) => str.length !== 0).join('\n');
      
 console.log(adsList)
```

Hi there I've an array and I'm basically returning the string if object contains checked property and separating them with semicolon, but need to remove for the last one.

I'm not sure how do I remove the last semicolon after `unspecified` from the output in this case, any leads would be quite helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't add the semi-colon in the `map` call, but use it as separator in the final `join` call.

Not an issue, but:

- you can use `Boolean` as filter callback function.
- Instead of returning `''`, you can return `.checked` when it is falsy, which allows you to return one expression without `if..else`.
- Maybe use a template string for concatenating the properties with commas.

```js
const arr = [{"id": "753311","role": "System Of Record (SOR)","license": "Target","DC": "Client · L2 (Inactive), Account · L1","managedGeography": "North America · L2, International · L2","managedSegment": "Institutional Clients Group [L3], Discontinued Ops [L2]","checked": true,"checkBoxPatched": true},{"id": "752872","role": "Authorized Redistributor (AR)","license": "Interim","DC": "Holding · L1, Document · L1, Compliance · L1","managedGeography": "Unspecified","managedSegment": "Unspecified","checked": true,"checkBoxPatched": true},{"id": "752583","role": "Authorized Redistributor (AR)","license": "Target","DC": "Agreement · L1, Asset · L1, Activity · L1, Account · L1","managedGeography": "Unspecified", "managedSegment": "Unspecified"}];

let adsList = arr.map(obj =>
    obj.checked && `${obj.role}, ${obj.license}, ${obj.DC}, ${obj.managedGeography}, ${obj.managedSegment}`
).filter(Boolean).join(';\n\n');
      
 console.log(adsList)
```

Comment: map + filter loops the array two times, when the reduce only one.

Comment: @spikef Not really much of an issue unless iterating over a **very** large dataset.

Answer (score 2):

You could update the code to join the array with `;\n` and if you want to keep the extra line in between then `;\n\n`

```
let adsList = arr.map(selectedObj => {
    if (selectedObj.checked) {
        return selectedObj.role + ", " + selectedObj.license + ", " + selectedObj.DC + ", " + selectedObj.managedGeography + ", " + selectedObj.managedSegment;
    } else {
        return '';
    }
}).filter((str) => str.length > 0).join(';\n');
```

```js
const arr = [{
    "id": "753311",
    "role": "System Of Record (SOR)",
    "license": "Target",
    "DC": "Client · L2 (Inactive), Account · L1",
    "managedGeography": "North America · L2, International · L2",
    "managedSegment": "Institutional Clients Group [L3], Discontinued Ops [L2]",
    "checked": true,
    "checkBoxPatched": true
  },
  {
    "id": "752872",
    "role": "Authorized Redistributor (AR)",
    "license": "Interim",
    "DC": "Holding · L1, Document · L1, Compliance · L1",
    "managedGeography": "Unspecified",
    "managedSegment": "Unspecified",
    "checked": true,
    "checkBoxPatched": true
  },
  {
    "id": "752583",
    "role": "Authorized Redistributor (AR)",
    "license": "Target",
    "DC": "Agreement · L1, Asset · L1, Activity · L1, Account · L1",
    "managedGeography": "Unspecified",
    "managedSegment": "Unspecified"
  }
]

let adsList = arr.map(selectedObj => {
  if (selectedObj.checked) {
    return selectedObj.role + ", " + selectedObj.license + ", " + selectedObj.DC + ", " + selectedObj.managedGeography + ", " + selectedObj.managedSegment;
  } else {
    return '';
  }
}).filter((str) => str.length > 0).join(';\n\n');

console.log(adsList)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [slice()](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) method to remove the last character from the resulting string:

```
let adsList = arr.map(selectedObj => {
  if (selectedObj.checked) {
    return selectedObj.role + ", " + selectedObj.license + ", " + selectedObj.DC + ", " + selectedObj.managedGeography + ", " + selectedObj.managedSegment + ";\n"
  } 
  return '';
}).filter((str) => str.length !== 0).join('\n').slice(0, -2);

console.log(adsList)
```

Comment: you don't need else and return, return is enough

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following regular expression:

```
/;(\s|\\n)*$/
```

To find a semicolon in the end of the string, then replace it with an empty string.

The regular expression has the following meaning:

`;` matches the literal semicolon

`(\s|\\n)*` matches one or more white spaces, or `\n` literals

`$` matches the end of the string

```js
const arr = [
    {
        "id": "753311",
        "role": "System Of Record (SOR)",
        "license": "Target",
        "DC": "Client · L2 (Inactive), Account · L1",
        "managedGeography": "North America · L2, International · L2",
        "managedSegment": "Institutional Clients Group [L3], Discontinued Ops [L2]",
        "checked": true,
        "checkBoxPatched": true
    },
    {
        "id": "752872",
        "role": "Authorized Redistributor (AR)",
        "license": "Interim",
        "DC": "Holding · L1, Document · L1, Compliance · L1",
        "managedGeography": "Unspecified",
        "managedSegment": "Unspecified",
        "checked": true,
        "checkBoxPatched": true
    },
    {
        "id": "752583",
        "role": "Authorized Redistributor (AR)",
        "license": "Target",
        "DC": "Agreement · L1, Asset · L1, Activity · L1, Account · L1",
        "managedGeography": "Unspecified",
        "managedSegment": "Unspecified"
    }
]

let adsList = arr.map(selectedObj => {
        if (selectedObj.checked) {
          return selectedObj.role + ", " + selectedObj.license + ", " + selectedObj.DC + ", " + selectedObj.managedGeography + ", " + selectedObj.managedSegment + ";\n"
        } else {
          return '';
        }
      }).filter((str) => str.length !== 0).join('\n').replace(/;(\s|\\n)*$/, '');
      
 console.log(adsList)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `reduce` but not `map + filter + join` like this:

In this way, you just need to loop the array one time.

```js
function handle(arr) {
  return arr.reduce((str, selectedObj) => {
    if (!selectedObj.checked) return str;
    const row = `${selectedObj.role}, ${selectedObj.license}, ${selectedObj.DC}, ${selectedObj.managedGeography}, ${selectedObj.managedSegment}`;
    return str ? str + ';\n\n' + row : row;
  }, '');
}

const arr = [{
    "id": "753311",
    "role": "System Of Record (SOR)",
    "license": "Target",
    "DC": "Client · L2 (Inactive), Account · L1",
    "managedGeography": "North America · L2, International · L2",
    "managedSegment": "Institutional Clients Group [L3], Discontinued Ops [L2]",
    "checked": true,
    "checkBoxPatched": true
  },
  {
    "id": "752872",
    "role": "Authorized Redistributor (AR)",
    "license": "Interim",
    "DC": "Holding · L1, Document · L1, Compliance · L1",
    "managedGeography": "Unspecified",
    "managedSegment": "Unspecified",
    "checked": true,
    "checkBoxPatched": true
  },
  {
    "id": "752583",
    "role": "Authorized Redistributor (AR)",
    "license": "Target",
    "DC": "Agreement · L1, Asset · L1, Activity · L1, Account · L1",
    "managedGeography": "Unspecified",
    "managedSegment": "Unspecified"
  }
]

const adsList = handle(arr);

console.log(adsList)
```